# How upload geoserver on openshift tomcat application

Tags: tomcat, geoserver, openshift

I made an openshift application in Tomcat type(jbossews-1.0) and want to uplaod Geoserver on it. I changed my geoserver.war as described here:http://dubrovsky.posterous.com/geoserver-on-openshift and git add it in my apps name/webapps. but it doesn't work whereas I add simple "Hello World" in webapps and it worked. How can I run my application?

Comment: Did you get errors when you deployed the application?  Anything useful in the logfile?  If so, please add that info to your question.

Comment: Hey I am going to write a blog post on this soon. You don't need those changes he suggested because those are for JBOSS specific issues. Which war file are you using? Let me know and I will get started on the blog post.

Comment: when I open my app the log file shows "INFO:Unregistering JAI Factory Class com.media.jai.opimage.shearRIF    org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener contextdestroyed. This line has been repeated many times with different end.

Comment: @Steve:I'm waiting to read your blog post.I downloaded geoserver.war from its site and then uploaded my data by using local Tomcat.At the end I make new web Dynamic project in Eclipse and replaced my geoserver content in web content folder and export it as war file. I test it in my local Tomcat and it worked. Are there any mistake in my procedure?Does it need to upload my geoserver somewhere for you to see it?

Comment: Did you see my note below? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post is here 
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift

It has a github repo that should work out of the box